# Extending of isomorphism $f: SO(2, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{T}$ to a homomorphism $GL(2, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{T}$.

Tags: group-theory, matrices

In [Arhangel'skii-Tkachenko, Topological groups and related structures](http://books.google.ch/books?id=B785AETmFKEC) on page 6 there is a theorem 1.1.6:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of an Abelian group $G$. Then every homomorphism $f$ of $H$ to any divisible group $F$ can be extended to a homomorphism of $G$ to $F$.

I am thinking about an example of non-commutative group $G$ to demonstrate that if we remove assumption that $G$ is Abelian, then the above theorem is no longer valid. 
I have an idea to start with well-known isomorphism $f: SO(2, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{T}$ where $\mathbb{T}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$ (multiplicative group).

My hypothesis is that there is no extension of isomorphism $f$ to some homomorphism of $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{T}$, but I am not able to prove or reject it.

Comment: It is “homomorphism” everywhere, not “homeomorphism”, I guess. And yes, this is only for abelian groups.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected that. And I believe that mentioned assumption is necessary. However I can construct some example to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derived subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ equals $SL(2,\mathbb R)$.   Thus any homomorphism from $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ to $T$
contains $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ in its kernel.  In particular, it contains
$SO(2,\mathbb R)$.  Thus no non-notrivial homomorphism from $SO(2,\mathbb R)$ to $T$ can be extended to $GL(2,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your argument. Hovever, I am not sure why any homomorphism from $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ to $T$ contains $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ in its kernel.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am only a beginner in this field. I know that if we for example consider homomorphism $f$ from $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R^{\times}}$ defined $f(A)=\mathrm{det}(A)$ for $A \in GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ then $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is its kernel. Hovever, I am not sure why $\mathbf{any}$ homomorphism from $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ to $T$ contains $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ in its kernel.

Comment: @mcihak: Dear Michak, If $G$ is any group, its derived (or commutator) subgroup $G'$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by all elements of the form $g_1 g_2 g_1^{-1} g_2^{-1}$, with $g_1, g_2 \in G$.  Any homomormorphism of $G$ to an abelian group necessarily contains $G'$ in its kernel.  When $G = GL(2,F)$ for a field $F$, one can show that $G' = SL(2,F)$.  Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think it will help me soon, but I must first learn about commutators. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

We can construct a required counterexample as follows. Let $H$ be an arbitrary divisible group such that the group $Hom(H)$ of homomorphisms of the group $H$ contains a non-inner homorphism $\alpha$ (that is, there is no element $g\in H$ such that $\alpha(h)=g^{-1}hg$ for each element $x\in H$) (for instance, we may take $H=\mathbb R$ and $\alpha(x)=-x$ for each $x\in H$). Let $G$ be a semidirect product of the groups $H$ and $Hom(H)$, that is a direct product $H\times Hom(H)$ endowed with a multiplication $(h_1,\alpha_1) (h_2,\alpha_2)=
(h_1\alpha_1(h_2), \alpha_1\alpha_2)$ for every elements $h_1, h_2\in H$ and 
$\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in Hom(H)$. Put $g_0=(e,\alpha^{-1})$. Then $g_0^{-1}hg_0=\alpha(h)$ for each element $h\in H$. Let $f:H\to H$ be the indentity isomorphism. Suppose that there exists a homomorphic extension $f’:G\to H$ of the homomorphism $f$. Put $g=f'(g_0)$. Then 
$g^{-1}hg=\alpha(h)$ for each element $h\in H$, a contradiction.

Comment: Dear Alex, The determinant of $A/\det A$ is $(\det A)^{-1}$.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Thanks.    .

Comment: Thank you very much for interesting counterexample!